# How to add static attribute to ES6 class

Tags: javascript, oop, static, attributes, ecmascript-6

We know very well that `class` of ES6 brought also : `static`, `get` as well as `set` features  :

However , it seems that `static` keyword is reserved only for Methods :

```
class Person {

    // static method --> No error
    static size(){
    }   
  // static attribute --> with Error
    static MIN=10;
}
```

How to be able to write `static` attribute within ES6 class to have something like the static attribute `MIN`.

We know that we can add the following instruction after class definition :

```
Person.MIN=10;
```

However , our scope is to find the way to write this **instruction inside class block**

Comment: Maybe you should check `JS` spec and maybe you find a way to send a feature request to crockford.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use static getter:

```js
class HasStaticValue {
  static get MIN() {
    return 10;
  }
}

console.log(HasStaticValue.MIN);
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot reach your scope with ES6 unless static getter , however , you may can  in ES7.

Anyway, [Babel](https://esnextb.in/?gist=ad168ed095aeac5ce098) support now the wanted syntax (check http://babeljs.io/) :

```
class Foo {
  bar = 2
  static iha = 'string'
}

const foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.bar, foo.iha, Foo.bar, Foo.iha);
// 2, undefined, undefined, 'string'
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd need a method to return the attribute, otherwise its only accessible within the class, which defeats the point of what you're trying to do with static.

Comment: Pessimist .. we need something optimist .